# How can i search using list/menu option in php?

Tags: php

Hi every body and plz help me

i want to use search in php through list. if i select any one option from list and click on search button than find me that records which i want to search.

e.g. i've create list for two values like female and male.

Comment: So have I got this right? You want to search (something) by allowing the user to pick the search terms from drop down lists? That bit would be fairly easy html but what are you then searching through?

Comment: yes i want to search through drop down list and plz give me idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for **Dynamic Dependent Dropdown Lists** in HTML/PHP. You may also need to use a database (MySQL/SQL) and Javascript depending on what you are trying to achieve.

Here are some links that may help get you started:

- http://www.huanix.com/2006/12/25/dynamic-dependent-drop-down-select-forms-using-php-mysql-and-javascript/
- http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/cookbook/24/

We can help you more once you've provided a bit more information and perhaps some snippets of code and insight as to what you've tried.